# Let less work like cat, if only one screen full of text

Tags: less, cat, pager

On my Debian machine here, `less` always opens the alternate screen to show stuff.

This is annoying, if there are only 2 or 3 lines to be displayed. I'd like `less` to:

- work as pager, if there is more than a screenful of information
- and work like `cat`, if there's not.

Apparently, `less` has the `-F` flag for "single screen" cases:

> -F or --quit-if-one-screen
>
> Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.

But in my case it just exits again, and no info is displayed. It's more like `cat /dev/null` and thus not really useful.

Has anyone an idea, how to achieve this `less` behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `-F` with `-X`, which disables the terminfo initialization sequence.

```
export LESS=-FX
```

This has the (dis)advantage that `less` does not clear displayed text on exit, no matter how long the file was.

Comment: Cool, that is quite exactly what I was looking for. That the screen is not cleared is just a minor drawback.

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/215313/102281) by [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity), you can pass `-F -X` to achieve this, but it means `less` will leave lots of text in your terminal scrollback (and it might not even be in order, if you jump around the text in `less`). `less` outputting nothing when you only pass `-F` is [known issue #303](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html).

Instead you can use a wrapper script. For slow inputs, like `git log -Gregex`, do you want:

A) lines to appear on the main screen as they come in, then switch to the alternate screen once scrolling is needed (so the first `$LINES` of output will always appear in your scrollback); if so, go with the 2nd of [Gilles's answers to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107355/85237).

B) lines to appear on the alternate screen, but quit the alternate screen and print the lines to the main screen if scrolling turns out to be unnecessary (so no output will appear in your scrollback if scrolling was required); if so, look at [my answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205260/85237).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a small wrapper script, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( $(wc -l < "$1") < ${LINES:-20} ))
then
        cat "$1"
else
        less "$1"
fi
```

If you create that in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin` as a file called something like `less2` (you might want to use a very short name like `l` for easy typing), and make sure it is executable with `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/less2`, you can use it in place of `less` for commands of the form `less filename`, i.e., `less2 filename` (or `l filename`).

This won't work if you are piping another command’s output through `less`,
or if you specify option(s) or multiple filenames.

It will no doubt be possible to do the same thing without the extra script file, by defining <strike>an alias</strike> a function, if you prefer.

Comment: **`s/an alias/a function/`** Attempting to cram an `if` statement that uses `$1` into an alias is road to madness. Defining a function, on the other hand, is as easy as `less() { if ...; then cat "$1"; else command less "$1"; fi; }`

Comment: You could update the script with use of `HEIGHT=$(stty size | awk '{ print $1 }')`. Then, yes, would it be a useful extension. Thanks for this option.

Comment: @Boldewyn: `bash` has `$LINES` (and `$COLUMNS`), which it updates automatically upon receiving a `SIGWINCH`. (And, if `checkwinsize` is on, every time the prompt is displayed.)

Comment: I use this code https://github.com/mpapis/home_dotfiles/blob/master/.functions#L3-30 it will cat short files and will enable line numbers when file names ends with :{line}